# Error: Could not find or load main class error when compiling in eclipse and command prompt But works in intelliJIDEA

Tags: java, classpath

I have been facing this simple issue yet not able to fix this. Getting this error both in eclipse as well as while running from command prompt.

This question is asked many times here I know, but didn't quiet get the solutions from any of those.

Just trying to understand things. Here is this simple to try program which I have.

```
package com;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hellooooooo");
    }

}
```

In eclipse I get this `Error: Could not find or load main class com.Test`

Now when I try from command Prompt.

```
C:\workSpaceLatest\Test\src\com>java Test
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

When I run `C:\workSpaceLatest\Test\src\com>javac Test.java`  no Error also no Output

[image]

But in IntelliIDEA it works fine. why is it so.
Someone help me understand this for once.

**P.S :  Point me to any posts or questions which has best answer. I haven't found any though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `com` as package the class name will be `com.Test` so to run the class run is from `C:\workSpaceLatest\Test\src` folder as follows after compilation.

```
C:\workSpaceLatest\Test\src>java com.Test
```

[image]

Note: You can compile the class as you do now.

Comment: Is `Test.class` present in the `C:\workSpaceLatest\Test\src\com` folder?

Comment: Yes it is present